# Laravel foreach undefined array key 1

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to update a column on all the data using a db seeder but I keep getting:
**Undefined array key 1**

I checked the $key on the foreach and it's value is 0.

```
Application::chunk(500, function($applications) {
    foreach($applications as $application){
        $questions = $application->vacancy->questions()->pluck('id')->toArray();
        if(!empty($questions)){       
            foreach ($application->answers ?? [] as $key => $value) {
                $value->update(
                    [
                        'vacancy_question_id' => $questions[$key]
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**Update**

Here's the relationship for application and answers

```
/**
 * Get the answers for the application.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function answers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error given by PHP? "Undefined array key 1" does not look right. Also, you can do an `if (empty($questions)) continue;` and unindent the nested for loop. Have you tried the nested for loop without the `??` syntax? The null coalescing operator inside the foreach looks gross in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

`$key` is only `0` at the first iteration of the foreach.
Then, it's `1`, then `2`...

When you call `dd($key);`, it shows `0` then stops the script. So you don't see other iterations of your foreach. If you want the script to continue, use `dump($key);` and you'll see that `$key` is `0`, then `1`...

At some point, it must be an index that is not in the `$questions` array.

```php
Application::chunk(500, function($applications) {
    foreach($applications as $application){
        $questions = $application->vacancy->questions()->pluck('id')->toArray();
        if(!empty($questions)){       
            foreach ($application->answers ?? [] as $key => $value) {

                // These lines will help you identifiy the problem

                if(!array_key_exists($key, $questions)){
                   dd($key.' missing from $questions!', $key, $questions);
                }

                $value->update(
                    [
                        'vacancy_question_id' => $questions[$key]
                    ]
                );
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I did this and got "1 missing from $questions!" but shouldn't the key be 0 ? where did the 1 came from ? I even dd($key) inside the foreach loop and it gives 0.

Comment: `dd($key.' missing from $questions!', $key, $questions);` prints all 3 things: `$key.' missing from $questions!'`, then `$key` then `$questions` at the same time, for debugging purpose. If you had `1 missing from $question`, then when `$key` is `1`, it bugs because `$questions` has no `1` index (key).

Comment: I updated my answer with an explanation about why you only see `0` when you `dd($key);`

Comment: that's weird, why does $key get incremented. It should have stopped on the for loop. I've updated my question attaching the relationship

Comment: `$key` is the representation of the `$application->answers` index. If there are 3 entries in this Collection, then `$key` will be `0`, then `1` then `2`. It is not "incremented". It's just the index of the current `$value` (current answer). Said otherwise, it's the position of the `$value` inside `$application->answers`